# Could there be a being made of gas complex enough to be sentient?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, xenobiology

Basically, could a gas stick together enough to be internally coherent, and act like animal cells? Or is there zero chance of that happening?

Comment: Not of "ideal gas". Ideal gas (and real gases are more or less ideal) is a homogeneous mix that does not have any structure by definition.

Comment: For any kind of interesting behavior you have to consider a plasma (somewhat like a ionized gas) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics). It has much more complicated and interesting behavior than a normal gas. I've no idea if it can become complex enough to reach what you are asking.

Comment: **A** gas very obviously cannot. Living things work by exquisite chemical reactions between *different* substances. (And gases don't "stick together". That's the *definition* of a gas -- a fluid which expands to fill available volume. A fluid which "sticks together" is called a liquid.)

Comment: Have you ever been out in a particular foggy day or night?  It always seems like the particles are caressing you but lack the full strength to full out hug you.  Why wouldn't you think that there was some level of sentience infused in those conditions?  It wouldn't take much redefinition of sentience to give the fog whispers and a more intimate investigation of people out in it.

Comment: A gas normally exists at equilibrium, maximum entropy.  One thing that lifeforms all have in common is that they all have lower entropy than their surroundings, and they maintain this low entropy while alive.  You'd have to have some mechanism, in the gas or working on the gas, causing it to do work and causing it to have a metabolism.  You'd probably need some mechanism for storing information (similar to DNA), and a mechanism for reading that info and causing a specific action as a result.  These are the requirements for simple life, let alone sentience.

Comment: Now if we're talking about it being mostly gas, as opposed to all gas, it becomes much easier to have lifeforms and sentience.

Answer (score 3):

This greatly depends on what you define as consciousness. Do you need to have full body to be a consciousness? Do you need to have a physical brain?

**What do you need to have to be a conscious being?**

So I'm going to get technical here - **neural networks**. A definition from the interwebs is as follows:

> Neural networks are a set of algorithms, modeled loosely after the human brain, that are designed to recognize patterns. They interpret sensory data through a kind of machine perception, labeling or clustering raw input.

As you'd expect, the *neural* part refers to the *neurons* in our brain. Every thought a human has is effectively a ridiculously complicated pattern of neurons firing off in our heads.

> Most neurons have a cell body, an axon, and dendrites.

Again, if you know a little code, that's a lot like a node's self pointer, node's next/previous pointer (this relationship allows the neural networks in our brains to act like the perfect undirected graphs).

What does this have to do with anything? Well, when I was talking about neurons firing off, this is literally as a result of electrical pulses. We're not talking about high voltage drops but it's electric nonetheless.

**So, what if we defined a conscious being as an arrangement of matter that could self-determine complex patterns of neurons conducting electrical pulses?**

This would mean that this gaseous being's *nervous system* would be some sort of conductive gas. I'm thinking about some sort of partially ionized noble gas like Helium, Neon, or Argon at different charges. Maybe even a combination of all of them.

I would argue that the rest of this being needs to be structured to maintain the relative physical integrity of this creature, so each *nerve* on this being would be surrounded by some sort of denser arrangement of gases. This could be a large number of CH4 or C2H6 (methane or ethane) molecules held together by weak london dispersion forces. Their presence not only would provide a physical 'barrier' between the being's nervous system but be non-polar enough to protect the nervous system from sudden changes in temperature while allowing it to still be influenced by the outside. This would work similar to how our skin, tissue, and muscle prevent our nerves from having to interact with the world directly. I would like to call this the being's **gassy exoskeleton**.

For more complex matters, like objectively 'grounding' these beings so they don't just float off, you would need the presence of 'heavier' matter to act as an anchor to a center of gravity. Even relatively dense gases are chaotic. I personally think some sort of ferric gas would be cool to see to add to the structure provided by the weak gassy exoskeleton I mentioned earlier. Or you can try and me cool and throw in some Cobalt or something.

Obviously, not much of this is grounded in reality. We have no evidence that something like this can exist, and I'm no specialist in this field either. I admit, I got carried away by this question, so the actual answers are below:

1. *The odds of something like this happening on a planet like ours (rocky, etc.)?* **Probably 0**. Might not be, but the conditions I've listed are really hard to come by, especially because the vast majority of the mass on a rocky planet is in fact, solid.
2. *The odds of something like this happening on a gas planet (or Venus)?* **Kind of high(ish)**. Gas planets are gassy, and if the right ingredients are present and chaos organizes itself just right, maybe your sentient gassy people will come to being.

Life is incredible because the odds of matter coming together on its own is shown to be incredibly improbable - even when all the materials are there. Sure, we don't everything about how life comes into fruition, but it has to mean something unique... *right*? That's all up to your own judgement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: See neural networks are more of a software oriented idea used extensively in Machine Learning, Artificial Intelligence, and Data Science. You want something more physical, I suggest you search of Neuromorphic Computing, which is the same thing but 'visible' on a chip. It's very complicated and you realize that we're way too far from making basic patterns show up on chips through neural propagation on a chip, let alone doing so on organic materials or gases.

I'm not saying your intelligent gas-people are impossible, but you need a lot of coincidences to happen just right to make it so.

Comment: Yeah, thats basically what I was thinking, but i dont have enough physics knowledge to know how feasible it would. Apparently the answer is "not zero but we have no idea" haha, Well, I guess I will use some of the answers here and take some liberties, thanks!

Comment: This is basically the plot to the Futurama episode where Bender meets God.